# C++ program crashed when loading array of objects

Tags: file, io

Hello i'm trying to fill an array of objects from a text file in c++ , but i have a crash every time i run the program. I'm i at the right direction here? Is there any more eficient way to do it?

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include "Item.h"

using namespace std;

void readItems(FILE *products, Item pList[]);

FILE *products;
int main()
{

    Item pList[5];

    readItems(products,pList);
    return 0;
}

void readItems(FILE *products, Item pList[]){

products = fopen("data.txt", "r");

int i = 0;
fread(&pList[i], sizeof(pList), 1, products);
while (!feof(products))
{
    i++;
fread (&pList[i], sizeof(pList), 1, products);

}

fclose(products);
}
```

Item.cpp

```
#include "Item.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Item::Item()
{
    code = 0;
    description = "";
    price = 0;
}

Item::Item(int code1,string description1,float price1)
{
    code = code1;
    description = description1;
    price = price1;
}

void Item::printData(){
    cout<<endl<<"Code:"<<code<<"\tName:"<<description<<"\tPrice:"<<price;
}

void Item::setData(int code1,string description1,float price1){
    code = code1;
    description = description1;
    price = price1;
}

int Item::getCode(){
    return code;
}

float Item::getPrice(){
    return price;
}

Item::~Item()
{
    //dtor
}
```

---

The new code is like that , but it prints a set of some chars of the txt file with some weird symbols .

```
void readItems(FILE *fin, Item list[]){
    int i=0;

    products = fopen("items.txt","r");
    fread(&list[i],sizeof(list[i]),1,products);
    list[i].printData();
    while(!feof(products) && i<5){
            fread(&list[i],sizeof(list[i]),1,products);
            list[i].printData();
            i++;
}

    fclose(products);
}
```

Comment: `fread`ing structures has a chance to work with POD types; if you have something like `std::string`, or virtual methods, or just about anything C++-specific in your `Item`, you have to [de]serialize it field-by-field. `Item.h` is missing so I have to guess... but isn't `description` std::string? (Well, it would break anyway even if `description` is `char*`...)

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
while (!feof(products))
{
    i++;
fread (&pList[i], sizeof(pList), 1, products);

}
```

with

```
while (!feof(products) && (i < 5))
{
    i++;
fread (&pList[i], sizeof(pList), 1, products);

}
```

Comment: Still crashing mates... i'm out of juice... :(